# I have a git error "[remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)"on push

Tags: git, gitlab

I am logged into Gitlab. I created a project, private.
I cloned the project out onto my local, ok.
I but when I do a push

```
git push -u origin main

[remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)

error: failed to push some refs to
```

I thought, if I can take a project, out I can make changes to it.
I dont own the gitlab.
But I can logon to it, and create projects, and clone then onto my local.